# Creating Popup Options Box with multiple buttons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, input, joptionpane

I'm trying to use java to create an popup input box with multiple options but I do not know what the easiest way to do this is. Currently when I click on a button in my GUI, this is what it does:

```
public class LoadListAction implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(f, "Test:");      
    }
}
```

however, this only gives me options of ok and cancel. I would like to have a box that popus up and has option 1 and option 2 on it and do different things to whatever is in the input box depending on which button is pressed.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: Ive tried using JDialog but it seems that I can't get both an input box as well as multiple buttons to click (or at least I don't know how).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) you can use the [add()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Component%29) to add as many components you want! As you can see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) , you can use many methods that are inherited from `Container` and `Component` in `JDialog`. yayy!

This is a copy-paste snippet from one of my program, hope you can get something from this:

---

```
jDialog1.setTitle("New Customer");
        jDialog1.setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(50, 50, 1092, 638));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("New Customer Details");

        jLabel3.setText("Name : ");

        jLabel4.setText("Address Line 1 : ");

        jLabel5.setText("Address Line 2 : ");

        jLabel6.setText("Address Line 3 : ");

        jLabel7.setText("Phone No : ");

        jLabel9.setText("Type of Customer : ");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "ORDINARY", "PREVILEGED" }));

        jButton6.setText("ADD CUSTOMER");
        jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton7.setText("REFRESH");
        jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton8.setText("CANCEL");
        jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jDialog1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jDialog1.getContentPane());
        jDialog1.getContentPane().setLayout(jDialog1Layout);
        jDialog1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1092, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(438, 438, 438)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap(502, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(228, 228, 228)
                .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton6)
                        .addGap(80, 80, 80)
                        .addComponent(jButton7)
                        .addGap(69, 69, 69)
                        .addComponent(jButton8)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 408, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 408, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 408, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 408, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 408, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(342, 342, 342))))
        );
        jDialog1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(75, 75, 75)
                .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 119, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jDialog1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6)
                    .addComponent(jButton8)
                    .addComponent(jButton7))
                .addGap(55, 55, 55))
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still don't understand how you use it though. I looked in your link and I didn't find an addComponent method, and I did find a addImpl which sounds like it adds components but I'm not sure how to fill some of its parameters. Could you give a brief example?

Answer (score 3):

You should try [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html).

- [How to use Dialogs?](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

JDialog can hold multiple buttons, textboxes, comboboxes, etc.. Just like a JFrame or JPanel does.

Comment: I read the link you gave me, but it seems like I either have to have multiple options and no input, or an input box with only 1 option. I don't know how to do both. I'm trying to use showInputDialog().

Comment: @Matt: as I have said You can add multiple components in JDialog. And if you still want to use `showInputDialog` then I have no idea on how to do this. May be you should read about customizing dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have a box that popus up and has option 1 and option 2 on it and do different things to whatever is in the input box depending on which button is pressed.

A JOptionPane doesn't support what you want because you have a confusing design that should be avoided.

It sounds like you want the user to enter values like "a, b, c". Then the user would click on buttons "1, 2, 3". Then different processing would result for a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3.

Not a very good design. Intead the popup should have either multiple input values and an Ok/Cancel button, or a single input value and multiple buttons to click.